# Report View - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: reporting-services, report, local

I use `VS2008` to develop a web application.

When I open a local report, it's report datasource does not show.
I click the report->DataSource to see it's datasource, but it appear an
error message:

> Could not load file or assembly ###

But the file or assembly does exist.

How can I solve this problem?

I searched everywhere and didnt found a solution for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Copy the assembly to the folder

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\ReportViewer`.

I use *SysInternals Process Monitor* to find where VS was looking for the containing file.

Answer (score 0):

The assembly may exist but in a place not seen by the app. Use filemon / procmon to find out where your app is trying to load the assembly from and you will have a clue of what's going on. Also make sure the assembly version matches as well.